# R: insert value in dataframe cell searching extracting it from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one dataframe looking as follows:

```
          Date     Element         Problem   Losses
   1  2020-09-29        54     Energy loss       NA
   2  2020-09-30        54           Fault       NA
   3  2020-09-30        54     Energy loss       NA
   4  2020-09-29        40         Cooling       NA
   5  2020-09-29        50         Voltage       NA
```

I would like to insert certain values in the `Losses` column whenever the `problem` column has the substring "Energy".

The values I need to insert are in another dataframe, looking like this:

```
       Date    Element       Losses
1 2020-09-29        54        13.24
2 2020-09-30        54        12.16
```

This is just an example, as the actual dataframes I'm using are pretty big, so I'd like to do this with some type of merge by the `Date` and `Element` columns, instead with looping through both dataframes.

**EDIT:**

I've tried using a merge by the `Element` column, so first I get the `Losses` repeteadly for all the corresponding elements, and then putting those rows where I don't have my desired substring back as Nan.

My problem here is that merging by `Element` deletes all my other rows, getting only the following:

```
          Date     Element         Problem   Losses
   1  2020-09-29        54     Energy loss    13.24
   2  2020-09-30        54           Fault       NA
   3  2020-09-30        54     Energy loss    12.16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
transform(df, Losses = insert_df$Losses[match(paste0(Date, Element, grepl("Energy", Problem)),
                                              paste0(insert_df$Date, insert_df$Element, "TRUE"))])
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18534, 18535, 18535, 18534, 
18534), class = "Date"), Element = c(54L, 54L, 54L, 40L, 50L), 
Problem = c("Energy loss", "Fault", "Energy loss", "Cooling", 
"Voltage"), Losses = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

insert_df <- structure(list(Date = structure(18534:18535, class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), Element = c(54L, 54L), Losses = c(13.24, 12.16)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!